# Точка в конце предложения после сокращения слова

Tags: сокращения, пунктуация

При написании предложения в конце стоит сокращение вида

```
... и т.д.
```

Можно (надо ли) после точки ставить еще одну, как символ окончания предложения? Аналогично — с запятой, если сокращение в середине предложения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Точка не ставится](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/41.htm) в конце предложения после точки, обозначающей сокращение слова.

Запятая в середине предложения после точки, обозначающей сокращение слова, может быть.

В сокращении "и т. д." "т." и "д." разделяются неразрывным пробелом.

Comment: Согласна с предыдущим ответом.

Comment: Что-то комментарий к ответу поставить не могу... Небольшая поправочка - "неразрывным пробелом".

Comment: Грамота.ру дает однозначный [ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=284238). _После точки как знака сокращения не ставится точка в конце предложения. В остальном точка как знак сокращения не влияет на пунктуацию: если оборот должен быть обособлен, он обособляется и при наличии в конце его сокращения с точкой_