# Нужна ли точка после сокращающей точки?

Tags: пунктуация, курсив, точка

В [данном вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476138/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F/476140#476140) я получил ответ, что ставятся обе точки.

А что, если использовать курсив? Какой вариант верен?

1. Верно с тире: *Это было в 2016 — 2020 гг.*. (Обе точки подряд.)
2. Верно с тире: *Это было в 2016 — 2020 гг.* . (Точки отбиты пробелом друг от друга.)
3. Верно с тире: *Это было в 2016 — 2020 гг.* (Точка остается только внутри курсива; в конце предложения не стоит.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точка не повторяется, кроме случаев с кавычками. Курсив никак не влияет.
Первые два варианта выглядят как опечатка.

[**Точка**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87) (Розенталь):

> **Примечание.** Точка не ставится в конце предложения после точки, обозначающей сокращение слова: *…и др.; …и пр.; …и т. д.; …и т. п.*

Comment: Значит, только в случае с курсивом нужно ставить обе? Когда курсив или полужирный (два других выделительных знака, помимо кавычек), там одна сохраняется?

Comment: Вы хотели написать "только в случае с кавычками"? Да, нигде не встретишь две точки в конце предложения, кроме как разделённых кавычками. Про курсив нигде не сказано, об этом  уже давно стало бы известно на этом сайте. Да и зрительно "курсивная" точка не отличается от обычной.

Comment: А что насчëт этого сайта? Где об этом известно здесь про точку? Есть ссылка(-и)?

Comment: Я к тому, что о точке после курсивной точки на этом сайте нет. Если бы было, то попалось бы. А про повтор вот, например:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/686/Точка-в-конце-предложения-после-сокращения-слова

Comment: Так разные же случаи. Курсив, полужирный и кавычки взаимозаменяемы. Это три выделительных знака для индентичных функций. Случай без курсива в конце — один случай, а когда нет курсива в конце — другой. Я спрашиваю про второй, а вы про первый.

Comment: Верно с тире: «Это было в 2016 — 2020 гг.».  Здесь всё понятно: точки разделены кавычками, они ставятся на разных основаниях — сокращение и конец предложения. Точка в курсиве не обладает такой выделительной функцией в сравнении с кавычками, она просто не в состоянии :) это сделать. Две точки в конце — ни туда ни сюда: то ли по ошибке напечатали лишнюю, то ли обгрызли многоточие. Вариант только один: ставится одна точка.